# Why is XPath failing to select anything from HTML?

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping

My HTML looks like

```
...
<lots of nested tags>
  <div class="tiles-tile">
    <div class="brick">
      <div class="brick-header">
        ...
        <ul class="links">
          <li><i class="icon-minus"></i></li>
          <li><i class="icon-resize-small"></i></li>
          <li><i class="icon-list"></i></li>
          <li><i class="icon-time"></i></li>
          <li><a></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</lots of nested tags>
<lots of nested tags>
  <div class="tiles-tile">
    <div class="brick">
      <div class="brick-header">
        ...
        <ul class="links">
          <li><i class="icon-minus"></i></li>
          <li><i class="icon-resize-small"></i></li>
          <li><i class="icon-list"></i></li>
          <li><i class="icon-time"></i></li>
          <li><a></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</lots of nested tags>
...
```

I've tried everything I can think of, by using XPath, to get a list of all `<i class="icon-list"` elements but I just cannot figure it out.

For instance I tried

```
//div[@class=\"brick-header\"]/ul/li/i[@class=\"icon-list\"]
```

but this gives me an empty list.

How do I do this?

Comment: What XPath did you try? This is a pretty straightforward XPath, so I am wondering were you did get stuck.

Comment: Why does your title ask about getting links but your example HTML show only `i` elements, no `a` elements or `href` links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following XPath will select all `i` elements of class `icon-list` regardless of ancestral elements:

```
//i[@class='icon-list']
```

### Reasons your XPath might not be working

1. There is a namespace declaration to take into account.

   **Remedy**: Declare proper namespace prefix and use it in the XPath (preferable), or test against the local name to avoid any namespace:

   ```
   //*[local-name()='i' and @class='icon-list']
   ```
2. There are other classes listed along with `icon-list`.

   **Remedy**: Use `contains()` rather than equality in the predicate:

   ```
   //i[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '), ' icon-list ')]
   ```
3. JavaScript is building or changing the markup structure after your
   XPath is running.

   **Remedy**: Wait to apply test until document has finished loading and JavaScript has finished running.

Comment: I gave three reasons why it might not be working.  Perhaps your response might include how you've checked each of the reasons rather than merely saying "it didn't work".   To try to help further, I've added remedies for each of the potential issues.   Thank you.